# how to match the color back ground of my frame with the master window

Tags: python, tkinter, background-color, customtkinter

thats the program in python using tkinter and customtkinter:

```
import customtkinter


def login():
    if email_entry.get() == "admin" and password_entry.get() == "password":
        message_label.configure(text="Login successful!")
    else:
        message_label.configure(text="Invalid username or password")

def sign_user():
    print('open another page and make the log')

def help_user():
    print('forget password?')

# window
window = customtkinter.CTk()
window.title("Agenda de Rotina")
window.geometry('500x300+710+390')
window.resizable(False, False)
customtkinter.set_appearance_mode('dark')

#create the frame to email and password
frame_1 = customtkinter.CTkFrame(window)
frame_1.pack(pady=(70, 5))

# create the email and password entry widgets
email_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(frame_1, text="E-mail:")
email_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
email_entry = customtkinter.CTkEntry(frame_1)
email_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

password_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(frame_1, text="Password:")
password_label.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
password_entry = customtkinter.CTkEntry(frame_1)
password_entry.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

# create the login button
login_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(window, text="Login", command=login)
login_button.pack(pady = 10)

# create a label for displaying messages
message_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(window, text="")
message_label.pack()

# create the frame to the sign and help? button
frame_2 = customtkinter.CTkFrame(window)
frame_2.pack(pady = 10)

# create the sign and need help? button
sign_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(frame_2, text = 'Sign', width = 100, command = sign_user)
sign_button.grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = (0, 10))
help_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(frame_2, text = 'Help?', width = 100, command = help_user)
help_button.grid(row = 0, column = 1, padx = (10, 0))


window.mainloop()
```

and  i used this appearance_mode:

```
customtkinter.set_appearance_mode('dark')
```

but i want to to my frame background color be the same as my bg window. I have tried to set, but doesn't work.

```
my_window_dark = '#242424'

# and i put the variable in the frame
frame_1 = customtkinter.CTkFrame(window, bg_color = 'my_window_dark')
frame_1.pack(pady=(70, 5))
```

and when i just put a random color to see what hapens:

[image]

i tried to creat a variable to the color and them put that variable in the color method of the frame, and get an error. Also when i put a random color that is in the lib, appear the image that i put above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the special color "transparent":

```py
frame_1 = customtkinter.CTkFrame(window, fg_color="transparent")
```

Comment: thanks for helping, im probably using your way. For what i want, its a lot clear and easy

Answer (score 1):

To match the color of the frame with the color of the parent window, you need to get the color of the parent and change the foreground color of the frame to it.

```
my_window_dark = window.cget("bg")

#create the frame to email and password
frame_1 = customtkinter.CTkFrame(window, fg_color=my_window_dark)
frame_1.pack(pady=(70, 5))
```